# Finding the difference between two signals

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have two signals, let's call them 'a' and 'b'. They are both nearly identical signals (recorded from the same input and contain the same information) however, because I recorded them at two different 'b' is time shifted by an unknown amount. Obviously, there is random noise in each.

Currently, I am using cross correlation to compute the time shift, however, I am still getting improper results.

Here is the code I am using to calculate the time shift:

```
function [ diff ] = FindDiff( signal1, signal2 )
%FINDDIFF Finds the difference between two signals of equal frequency 
%after an appropritate time shift is applied
%   Calculates the time shift between two signals of equal frequency 
%   using cross correlation, shifts the second signal and subtracts the
%   shifted signal from the first signal. This difference is returned.
length = size(signal1);

if (length ~= size(signal2))
    error('Vectors must be equal size');
end

t = 1:length;
tx = (-length+1):length;
x = xcorr(signal1,signal2);
[mx,ix] = max(x);
lag = abs(tx(ix));
shifted_signal2 = timeshift(signal2,lag);
diff = signal1 - shifted_signal2;

end

function [ shifted ] = timeshift( input_signal, shift_amount )
input_size = size(input_signal);
shifted = (1:input_size)';
for i = 1:input_size
    if i <= shift_amount
        shifted(i) = 0;
    else
        shifted(i) = input_signal(i-shift_amount);
    end
end

end

plot(FindDiff(a,b));
```

However the result from the function is a period wave, rather than random noise, so the lag must still be off. I would post an image of the plot, but imgur is currently not cooperating.

Is there a more accurate way to calculate lag other than cross correlation, or is there a way to improve the results from cross correlation?

Comment: Actually, if you're comparing two signals of the same size xcorr wont work because it it will begin by comparing signal1 with a only a portion of signal2 which will be padded with zeros (or maybe padded with the last value but this is still not a good way to compare two signals). You should probably be comparing a signal segment to a larger signal and then determine where the sub signal lies in the larger signal.

Also, you are overwriting "length" a built in function and forming t and tx unnecessarily.

Comment: @jucestain I don't think that is correct. The only thing we are looking at with the cross correlation is its max, so those zeros at the beginning will not have an effect. And I know that these functions work perfectly when a signal is used against itself.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the whole correlation instead of just its maximum? If dealing with real-world noisy signals, there is a chance that your real time shift doesn't produce the maximal correlation

Comment: @KyleRogers Read about how cross correlation works. It's a sliding dot product. If you are comparing two vectors of the same size, how do you think they are going to be compared at the beginning or end?  One of the vectors will be padded with something. From looking briefly at the xcorr output, it looks like it pads one of the vectors with zeros. Also, when you say "those zeros at the beginning will not have an effect," the correlation coefficient will be calculated using these values, so they will undoubtedly have an effect especially since your implementation doesnt use normalization.

Comment: @jucestain My code was actually completely correct. The reason I was getting results I thought were incorrect had to do with the instrumentation producing periodic noise, not gaussian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now there are two functions in Matlab:

one called [finddelay](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/finddelay.html)

and another called [alignsignals](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/alignsignals.html) that can do what you want, I believe.

Comment: Given the new function - this should now be considered the best solution to this problem.

Answer (score 7):

[Cross-correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) is usually the simplest way to determine the time lag between two signals. The position of peak value indicates the time offset at which the two signals are the most similar.

```
%// Normalize signals to zero mean and unit variance
s1 = (signal1 - mean(signal1)) / std(signal1);
s2 = (signal2 - mean(signal2)) / std(signal2);

%// Compute time lag between signals
c = xcorr(s1, s2);                       %// Cross correlation
lag = mod(find(c == max(c)), length(s2)) %// Find the position of the peak
```

Note that the two signals have to be normalized first to the same energy level, so that the results are not biased.

By the way, don't use `diff` as a name for a variable. There's already a [built-in function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) in MATLAB with the same name.

Comment: How can I tell from the lag if the signal2 could or could not be found in signal1?

Comment: @ZoltanSzabo It is the peak of the cross correlation, rather than the "lag", that helps you determine what you are asking about. The peak indicates where the two signals are the most similar, or in other words, what is the time shift between a signal and another similar signal. The absence of such a peak means that the signals are dissimilar.

Comment: Thanks, I could get the peak with the max index of the correlation. Do you know how can I get some percentage to show how similar are the two signals? For example I have two signals, which are almost similar. The length of the first signal is around 130kbyte, however the algorithm found the peak around 125kbyte, so it seems that it has found a match, but I know that the signals are not really similar. So I need some percentage.

Comment: @ZoltanSzabo there are numerous methods for measuring signal similarities. One of them is comparing the frequency components... I suggest you take a look at [this example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/examples/measuring-signal-similarities.html) from the official MATLAB documentation website.

Answer (score 1):

corr finds a dot product between vectors `(v1, v2)`. If it works bad with your signal, I'd try to minimize a sum of squares of differences (i.e. `abs(v1 - v2)`).

```
 signal = sin(1:100);
 signal1 = [zeros(1, 10) signal];
 signal2 = [signal zeros(1, 10)];

 for i = 1:length(signal1)
     signal1shifted = [signal1 zeros(1, i)];
     signal2shifted = [zeros(1, i) signal2];
     d2(i) = sum((signal1shifted - signal2shifted).^2);
 end

 [fval lag2] = min(d2);

 lag2
```

It is computationally worse than cross-calculation which can be speeded up by using FFT. As far as I know you can't do this with euclidean distance.

UPD. Deleted wrong idea about cross-correlation with periodic signals

Answer (score 0):

You can try matched filtering in frequency domain

```
function [corr_output] = pc_corr_processor (target_signal, ref_signal)
L = length(ref_signal);
N = length(target_signal);

matched_filter = flipud(ref_signal')';
matched_filter_Res = fft(matched_filter,N);
corr_fft = matched_filter_Res.*fft(target_signal);
corr_out = abs(ifft(corr_fft));
```

The peak of the matched filter maximum-index of corr_out above should give you the lag amount.